# My mentor thinks i am incompetent because of this

Tags: career-development, manager

Many of us might have faced this irrespective of the profession you are working but hear me out on this and please tell me what can anyone do to improve/ handle this situation in a professional manner.

I was reached out by a client for a simple problem that her credentials for a database were not working. So to access this database there are 2 types of credentials - 
1. Common ( used by others and has limited access )
2. Developer (as the name suggests it has full access and is used by developers only)

I had my developer credentials and so I tried them since her common credentials were not working on her machine and so I was able to access the database but what is even weird that everyone else around her was able to access the database using the common credentials but her. So a common sense clue I was getting is that she might be having a problem on her machine, but it wasn't because I told her that I will pull in my manager in the call and maybe he would be able to guide her out of this. My manager asked her to put her credentials ( common credentials ) and it worked !! I and the client were in shock because she had tried this in front of me in the call and it didn't work and now it did...

After the call, my manager explained to me how to deal with this problem on call. Much of what his voice and way of speaking suggested disappointment to handle a simple situation and that I am very incompetent. I am a fresher in this company by the way and so I am not given much work so you can imagine what he would think about in my appraisals and handling my responsibilities in the future.

**How do I approach a situation like this? Should I explain my manager or should I keep quiet and gulp my anger?**

Side-note - My manager happens to be a short-tempered guy who gets easily irritated

Trust me, I am not overthinking this. I think many of us have been here like me where I try to help someone with something and then some other guy comes and tries and the thing and it works... 
It really sucks how it feels after you go through something like this.

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: How do i approach a situation like this ? Should I explain my manager or should I keep quiet and gulp my anger ?

Comment: That's what weird  and trust me even the client feel the same way. So there's no way I can think of to explain my manager about this since obviously that way I am blaming a machine which sounds paranoid like I just saw god with my own eyes. People won't believe it

Comment: This happens all the time doing IT work. The computer doesn't seem to be working, then suddenly it does. You get used to it. Does your manager really think you are incompetent? Did they say so?

Comment: @Seth R You know what a crying baby sounds like ...So yes sir I know how my manager sounds like when he is disappointed.

Comment: Was this something you really needed to bring the manager in for? You could simply tell them to try a different desktop or reboot to see if they have the same issues. That's assuming after verifying that she has all the credentials to access the database.

Comment: Good support does not try one simple avenue and then escalate. You should have troubleshot further at the very least. So while your manager may have over reacted, he is correct in that there is no point having a support person who escalates straight away. Learn from this. Problem 2, you used your dev credentials on a client machine, change your password. Your credentials may have been captured. In a few minutes you made multiple errors, don't expect manager to be happy.

Comment: @Kilisi You're right and like you said I did not escalate it to the manager directly. I was troubleshooting with her for the past 3 days. In the end, my intention was to make everyone happy and to resolve her issue so i had to reach out to my manager. And no, my credentials did not get captured since I took control of the screen and typed the username and password in her machine myself, so unless there is some nifty piece of software I am not aware of, I can assure that I maintained all software developer ethics in this scenario.

Comment: @Dan I had to bring in my manager since I happen to work in a team where ther is no one else to help me with this, so the next level of hierarchy i could have reached out to was my manger. I understand your concern not to bother senior people but trust me i have to face this dielemma every time I am stuck somewhere and it leaves me with no other option but to take this call.

Comment: @Sagittarius009 My point is you shouldn't need to escalate this at all. It sounds like a simple issue and you simply panicked when what you thought should work did not. No work place is going to appreciate you escalating simple issues everytime you get stuck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was a problem.  You tried to solve it but it didn't work.  Manager tries the same solution, it now works.

Welcome to the wonderful world of IT.  I lost count of the number of times that stuff just magically started working when someone else was simply standing in the room.  Most likely she reboot her computer - there's a reason this is a meme.

At this point just take what the manager said and apply those steps next time.  Even if they were the exact same steps as you took before.  Just add in "turn it off, then on again" as step 1...

**edit**
I meant to add one more thing - Don't take it personally.  Laugh it off and move on.

Comment: There's even a phrase for this in video production:  "Engineer Proximity Syndrome" where things magically start working once the engineer is looking at it after the ops call them.

Comment: Sir belive me I also watch that TV series and she even rebooted her system, so this is beyond my imagination how it worked out

Comment: @NotMe Looks like that's what I have as an option lol..

Comment: @Sagittarius009: It's also entirely possible that the person kept entering the credentials in wrong.  Maybe the caps lock was on, maybe she recently lengthened her fingernails and it was catching on an extra key, maybe she forgot the right credentials and misremembered them until the manager showed up on the call and she decided not to tell you that she entered them in wrong from fear of appearing like an idiot.  (I've personally caught people on that one).

Comment: She was copying and pasting in front of me from notepad bruh....i am telling you looks like there is some magic in IT world and with time I'll get used to it...By the way you want me to close this thread since some people find it offensive for some reason

Comment: @Sagittarius009 there is no magic in the IT world. If the common password was working for everyone else (and worked for her later), then she was mistyping it. This is one of the most common mistakes in the world. Cut and paste doesn't eliminate the problem because folks will miscopy, and inadvertently ad extra characters after pasting.

Comment: @Sagittarius009 so when you asked to enter the password, she did copy & paste.  When your boss asked, did she type the password in, or use copy & paste?

Comment: @DaveG She tried both approaches in front of me, so either she was mistyping and mispasting in front of me which I would've made out by counting the number of character that appears when someone types a password or she had a correct attempt in front of my manager.

Comment: In medical training, we call this "The Touch of the Attending Physician." They may do EXACTLY the same thing, and sometimes it works.  Don't sweat it. Just make a joke about his magic fingers!